# how to get the value of the widget select?

Tags: python, django

please help bring the selected value of the widget select.

model.py:

```
class UserProfile(User):        
    CHOICES_teacher = (
        ('0', 'qwe', ),
        ('1', 'asd',),
        ('2', 'zxc', ),
    )       

    teacher = models.CharField(
        'teacher',
        max_length=30, 
        choices=CHOICES_teacher,        
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

forms.py:

```
class DrumDataForm(forms.ModelForm):            
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'teacher', 
        )
```

template.html:

```
{% if entries_user_profile.teacher %}
    <div class="teacher">{{ entries_user_profile.teacher }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

the problem is that the screen displays 0 or 1 or 2. but I need to them on screen qwe or asd or zxc

Comment: use {{ entries_user_profile.teacher.1 }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display):

> For every field that has [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) set, the object will have a get_FOO_display() method, where FOO is the name of the field. This method returns the “human-readable” value of the field.

Thus, in your example, you can access the "human-readable" value of the field using:

`{{ entries_user_profile.get_teacher_display }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ entries_user_profile.get_teacher_display }}
```